# Why does fish have a lower minimum safe-cooking temperature?

Tags: food-safety, bacteria, food-poisoning, virus

Food safety guidelines suggest cooking fish to at least 130F.
Chicken, in contrast, should be cooked to at least 165F.
Perhaps the bacteria/viruses found in fish die at lower temperatures. If so, why the bacteria/viruses found in chicken are not found in fish?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Seasoned Advice SE